# Meteor, create an empty cursor to return

Tags: javascript, meteor, cursor

For various technical needs, i want to assign an empty cursor to a variable. Is that possible without doing a search?

just like if I want to return an empty array, I do

```
var array = []
```

So instead of being forced to do:

```
var cursor = mystuff.find( { '$$$':'&&&&' }     //this will return an empty cursor
```

I want to do

```
var cursor = [how a cursor is made]
```

Comment: mystuff.find(null);